# Problema urllib2 con HTTPS

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy tratando de recuperar una pagina en Flickr utilizando urllib2 
y me tira el siguiente error cuando ejecuto el comando `urllib2.urlopen('https://www.flickr.com')`

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 104, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 361, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _open
    '_open', req)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 339, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1099, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1066, in do_open
    raise URLError(err) urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Al parecer el problema ocurre cuando me conecto con HTTPS porque con HTTP funciona. FLickr utiliza TLS 1.2. No se si es un problema de versiones o de SSL.

¿Alguien sabe?. Necesito conectarme por HTTPS. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente tendrás que especificar el protocolo SSL que quieres usar. Se puede pasar como *contexto* a `urllib2.urlopen`:

```
import ssl
import urllib2

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
req = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.flickr.com', context=context)
```

#### Editado

También asegúrate de estar usando la última revisión de python-2.7 (mínimo python-2.7.9). La librería SSL de python2 tiene graves fallos de seguridad y sólo las últimas revisiones reciben los parches creados desde python3.

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error... A vos te anda bien?

Comment: Y la versión de Python, ¿qué versión exacta estas usando? A mi me funcionó con python 2.7.11 sin problemas.

Comment: Estaba utilizando la 2.7.9 pero al parecer no era un problema de la versión. Probé con lo ultimo que es reinstalar Ubuntu y funciono. La verdad que no se fue cual fue el problema, gracias Igual....

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente realiza un ping a https://www.flickr.com para probar no tengas problemas para abrir el url, si estas bajo un proxy server seguramente el problema es porque te impide el acceso, o estas offline.

trata de esta forma:

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('https://www.flickr.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
contenido = response.read()
print contenido
```

Comment: Siegue igual, no funciona...

Comment: puedes acceder a la pagina web?  realiza un ping.

Comment: Si si ya probe de todo. Probé con lo ultimo que es reinstalar Ubuntu y funciono. La verdad que no se fue cual fue el problema, gracias Igual....

Comment: Ohhh entonces tuviste que reinstalar ubuntu y con eso se soluciono,  un poco raro, pero que bien, lo importante es  que ya funciono.